# How to restore a tar file in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I am trying to restore a .tar file in pgadmin 4.

I created a new empty database exercises.
Then clicked on exercises > create restore > select file path with data options as pre-data, data, post-data selected.
While restoring it, I am getting an error.
[image: Screenshot for pgadmin4]

[image: Error description logs]

Error Logs in plain text:

```
 C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\16\pgAdmin 4\runtime\pg_restore.exe --host "localhost" --port "5432" --username "postgres" --no-password --dbname "exercises" --section=pre-data --section=data --section=post-data --verbose "C:\\Users\\Bhaskar\\DOWNLO~1\\EXERCI~1.TAR"
```

I have also tried to restore without any data options too.

How to resolve this error

Comment: Stack Overflow is for _programming_ questions. Also, please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It got resolved after doing the following steps

Open up pgAdmin4 and go to:

```
File > Preferences > Paths > Binary paths > PostgreSQL Binary Path
 > select the appropriate postgres version(you may not have the default version listed)
> select the bin folder of the version selected and click validate > Click OK
```

Answer (score 0):

- Navigate to the Directory Containing the Tar File using terminal
- make sure PostgreSQL Server is Running:
- Run the pg_restore Command :

  `pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U your_username -d your_database_name your_backup_file.tar`

Explanation of the options:

-verbose: Show progress information.

- clean: Drop existing database objects before restoring.
- no-acl and --no-owner: Ignore access control lists and ownership information.
- h localhost: Specifies the host (you may need to adjust this).
- U your_username: Specifies the username to connect to the database.
- d your_database_name: Specifies the name of the database to restore.
- your_backup_file.tar: replace this with the actual name of your tar file.
  Adjust the options based on your specific needs and configuration.

Comment: "The code execution can not proceed because libzstc.dll was not found. Reinstalling the program may fix this problem" got this error with pg_restore.exe command

Comment: Yeah reinstall and see or else find the dll and add it to references. Make sure to mark it as correct answer and give a upvote. thanks in advance